How to load HTML file from from web url and show in WebView?
I have a web link that loading *.html file if I open it from browser. If i try to put this url as is in my WebView it's simply doesn't show anything.
I guess I need to load this HTML file somehow and show this content in WebView. Can you help me with that? :(
I found examples but they all show how to handle HTML files if they laying in assets but i need to get it from URL

Where is the file hosted? Try another URL (one that you know it works: https://stackoverflow.com/)

Show your code. We dont know what you do.
